# ASPxGridView - How to hide drop-downs in cascaded combo boxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can you please provide me some resolution to make the cascading dropdowns work as expected when used inside edit mode of AspxGridview.
I am using DevExpress Controls.

My requirement is as follow:

1. If I select country="United States" then populate the "State" combobox and on selection of "State" populate the "City" combobox.
2. If I select "country" other then "United States" then populate only "City" combobox with cities of selected "country" and no need to populate the "State" combobox. Also I need to hide the "State" combobox.

i.e. like 
     Country         State       City
ROW1 united states   Alaska      Douglas
ROW2 Canada                      Toronto
ROW3 Australia                   Sydeny
ROW4 united states   California  Yuba City

Same is required in Editmode also.

Please help me I need to do it ASAP.

Regards,
Pankaj.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a link to DevExpress' own demo of exactly that functionality.

[DevExpress Demos - Cascading Combo Boxes](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxComboBox/ClientAPI.aspx)

Will that do?